# Check if words from large MySQL DB is in string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large database with users (~1M) that each have their own *code*. All users can send *posts* with text (like a chat). I wan't to check if any of the user's code is in the *post*.

I could build up an array and loop through it like this:

```
// Text sent from $_POST
$text = "hey i am zlatan with code1";

// Loaded from MySQL and put into the array
$array = array('code1', 'code2');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    if (strpos($text, $array[$i]) !== false)
    {
        // At least one code was found, exit loop
        $foundCode = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

But I feel that the performance, doing a search for 1M codes for 1 chat message, is bad. What is your opinion about this and how could I improve it?

Comment: Let MySql search for it in the database, that is what it is for.

Comment: And how do I know what text to search with? If the message is `hey i am zlatan with code1`, how do I search with that in MySQL?

Comment: What is this code you talk about. Is it their user name or their ID on the database or something completely different

Comment: Could you also provide the structure of your MySql table? Are the search items always single words? Should words also match when they are part of a larger word?

Comment: The *code* consists of a length-wise stripped md5 string where all codes are unique. They do not represent the ID or anything like that. Why do you need the structure of the table? This is the row that holds the *code*: `recruit_link varchar(32) NOT NULL`

Comment: Do you think that the way I provided in the question would be efficient enough? Maybe cache all the user codes every ~30m in file and read from that?